# Convert txt file to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a .txt file that looks something like this: 
[txt file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4fcB.png)

So basically, it's a list of tweets that may or not contain a keyword and hashtag(s).

I want to convert this txt file to a JSON format using Python. I'm thinking something like this (for each tweet):

```
{"tweet": [
   "text": "actual tweet inserted here",
   "hashtag": "hashtags (just leave blank if there are none)",
   "keywords": "same as hashtags"
   ]
}
```

I think this is a valid JSON format, but I'm kinda lost on where to start.

I'm fairly new to Python and JSON, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried the json module... json.loads(string) its part of the standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html, you should start by going through the library.

Comment: you show almost valid Python dictionary which you can save as JSON file. So read file and create Python dictionary and then you can save it in JSON file.

Comment: BTW: in your example use `{} instead of `[]` and you will have valid JSON and valid Python dictionary.